# ¿Como Incorporar valores de las base de datos a un js?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Buenos días, es mi primera vez trabajando con ajax y quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que una variable en JS tome valores de la base de datos

Este es mi codigo en PHP para hacer el llamado de los datos de la base de datos

```html
<?php 
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "pass";

  $databaseName = "bd";


$link=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $databaseName);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
$results=array();

    $query="SELECT * FROM tasas";
    $show=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ("Error");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($show)){
       $results[] = $row['valor'];
       
    }   
    return $results[];
?>
```

Ahora quiero que los datos almacenados puedan reemplazar los valores que están acá para que tomen los valores de la base de datos

```js
 if (pickup == 0){
  tasaP = 10;
  descP = "Casa u oficina";
 }
 if (pickup == 1){
  tasaP = 0;
  descP = "Centro de acopio";
 }
 else if (pickup == 2){
  tasaP = 5;
  descP = "Aliado 1";
 }
 else if (pickup == 3){
  tasaP = 6;
  descP = "Aliado 2";
 }
 
 if (delivery == 0){
  tasaD = 5;
  descD = "Casa u oficina";
 }
 else if (delivery == 1){
  tasaD = 10;
  descD = "Centro de acopio";
 }
 else{
 tasaD = 0;
 }

 if (insurance == 0){
  tasaI = 10;
  descI = "Básico";
 }
 else if (insurance == 1){
  tasaI = 25
  descI = "Premium";
 }
 else{
  tasaI = 0;
 }

 if (type == 0){
  tasaC = 0;
  descC = "Paquete";
 }
 else{
  tasaC = 10;
  descC = "Documento";
 }
```

He leído que se hace con Ajax pero no logro entender como agarrar los valores y que reemplace los valores estáticos que tengo en mi js

Si es posible que alguien me explique detalladamente se lo agradecería

Comment: En el código php mandas un arreglo como json, y en ajax colocas un "success" y en la función cambias todo lo que vayas a cambiar

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no se puede, tu estás preguntando por modificar codigo javascript, por ejemplo modificar las variables de ese javascript descI... o lo que sea, ese ya de por sí es una buena chapuza. Lo que tienes que hacer es recuperar los datos de tu backend y tratarlos. Empieza leyendo algo, http://www.uco.es/~lr1maalm/manualdeajax.pdf

Comment: Me parece que quiere cambiar el valor de las variables, lo cual no es difícil si las declara como globales, en todo caso @Chicky Ng puedes aportar más detalles de lo que quieres hacer

Comment: @AndySamuelAlvarado exacto lo que quiero es que las variables que están en el if tomen los valores que tengo en la base de datos que estoy llamando desde mi archivo PHP

Answer (score 0):

Bien, efectivamente puedes usar ajax para hacer lo que deseas. Primero tienes que saber que el php tiene que devolver un json que AJAX pueda entender, así que te dejo la parte del código para pasar el arreglo de PHP a un JSON (No entendí mucho tu código, esto va luego de hacer la consulta. Tampoco sé usar Mysqli, pero es más o menos la misma idea):

```
$result = $statement->fetch();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $rows = array(
            'pickup ' => $result['pickup'],
            'delivery' => $result['delivery'],
            'insurance' => $result['insurance'],
            'type' => $result['type']
        );
echo (json_encode($rows, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)); //Esto equivale al return que tú pusiste
```

Ahora en el jquery, supongamos que quieres hacer el llamado cuando termine la carga de la página, quedaría así (suponiendo que los valores de pickup, delivery, insurance y type no los vuelves a usar, si quieres lo puedes guardar en variables globales si los necesitas de nuevo luego):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ruta/nombre.php', //tu archivo php
      method: 'POST',
      success : function(data){
      updateVariables(data['pickup'], data['delivery'], data['insurance'], 
      data['type']); //Los mismos nombres que pusimos en PHP
      }
    });

    function updateVariables(pickup, delivery, insurance, type){
        if (pickup == 0){
          tasaP = 10;
          descP = "Casa u oficina";
        }else if (pickup == 1){
          tasaP = 0;
          descP = "Centro de acopio";
        }else{
              if (pickup == 2){
                tasaP = 5;
                descP = "Aliado 1";
              }
              else if(pickup == 3){
                tasaP = 6;
                descP = "Aliado 2";
              }
              else{
                tasaP = ?;
                descP = ?;
              }
        }

        if (delivery == 0){
          tasaD = 5;
          descD = "Casa u oficina";
        }else if (delivery == 1){
          tasaD = 10;
          descD = "Centro de acopio";
        }
        else{
        tasaD = 0;
        }

        if (insurance == 0){
          tasaI = 10;
          descI = "Básico";
        }else if (insurance == 1){
          tasaI = 25
          descI = "Premium";
        }else{
          tasaI = 0;
        }

        if (type == 0){
          tasaC = 0;
          descC = "Paquete";
        }else{
          tasaC = 10;
          descC = "Documento";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Andy lo logre solucionar hoy, mi error era que al pasar el json no sabía que estaba mandando un string y al hacer console.log en el js me separaba caracter por caracter el json lo que hice fue json.parse(data) y funciono pero intentare tu modo para seguir aprendiendo